# Retrieving prompt information in ksh?

Tags: shell-script, ksh

If there is a prompt being read for a value such as:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "What is your name?"
read name

username=$name

rcmd machine1 grep $username /path/locnames >> namefile

rcmd machine1 cat namefile | less
```

What is required to retain prompt information from the `read` command properly?
For example, What I have here is a remote command(`rmcd`) using `grep` to list names in a locnames directory. Is there another command or technique to use to retain prompt information besides a `read` or using arguments `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc...?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking for; have you tried `ksh`'s `select` feature? It allows to select from a list of possible entries, and this list may be composed by the (file-)names in a directory, or if using command substitution also by names in a file.

Comment: What am asking is there a command other than read to store values from prompt....

Comment: I have not tried ksh's select feature though....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `read` is the most common way to read data "from prompts". And `select` is a more powerful feature that lets you use lists of data to select from. Inspect the latter to know about its usefulness for your specific purpose. Also note that `ksh`'s `read` supports a syntax to include the prompt; with your sample that could be: `read name?"What is your name? "`.

Comment: Are you referring to 'select' with case 'statements'?

Comment: @Juan Davila; I'm not sure why you say "with `case` statements." I'm using `select` also without a `case` statement, like (e.g.): `select game in *.ttyrec ; do  ipbt "${game}" ; done`. That way you will get a list of all "*.ttyrec" files presented, and you type in the index of the entry you want to select, which can then be used through the variable specified with `select`. You can define `PS3` to contain a prompt, then this prompt and a list of selectable entries will be displayed when calling `select`.

Comment: I mentioned `case` because I wanted to know if that meant an conditional statement. Though, this seems different. The `select` works similar to read with the exception of what?

Comment: @Juan Davila; The main difference is that a list of selectable is presented, and you can choose items from the list by an numeric index.